# Using camera2 along side Tango motion tracking

Tags: android, google-project-tango, android-camera2

I am trying to build a data logger with machine vision camera function. The most important part from camera2 api is the ability to set focus to infinite to me.

I recently got a Lenovo Phab 2 pro and have been exploring Tango's motion tracking and depth map functions. I would like to record the pose estimation and depth map from Tango alongside my original camera image. Although Tango seems to use only the fisheye camera and time of flight camera for those tasks, I am not able to get any reading for pose and depth map whenever I open the main back facing camera using camera2. I have been doing some research on Tango to see if it allows manual focus control. Unfortunately,I couldn't find anything useful.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to get Tango to work while having the back camera controlled by camera2?
- If not, is there a way to manually control the main camera's focus using Tango api?

Thank you all very much!